# concat a varying value to a variable in python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, concatenation

instead of repeating the line multiple times can I concat a varying value in a variable so I change the variable after every iteration in a loop

```
ac2=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 2, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
ac3=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 3, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
ac4=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 4, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
ac5=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 5, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
ac6=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 6, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
```

is there a method using for loop to make this shorter something like this-

```
for i in range(2,7):
    ac+i=AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = i, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary

```
val = {}
for i in range(2,7):
  val["ac{0}".format(i)] = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = i, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')

print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT RECOMMEND using the method below, but only for experimental purposes.

`globals()` returns `dict` of `key` as variabls and the `value` as the value assigned to the variable.

```py
for i in range(2, 7):
    globals()[f'ac{i}'] = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = i, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'average')
```

It will create variables from `ac2` to `ac6`.